# Adding fixed value after importrange formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

how to add auto numbering and fixed value to a importrange formula?

eg.

| No | Name | Qty | Price | Fixed Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1 | 4 | fresh |
| 2 | Nuts | 2 | 5 | fresh |

column 2 to 4 is data imported from another sheets, I want column 1 to auto number depending on how many row of data is imported, and in column Fixed Value I want it to have the value "fresh" which is the same for every row. I want to formula to populate these automatically field because the number of row is different for every instance and to I want to reduce manual input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For `Cell_A2` sequence:*

```js
=let(Σ,counta(B2:B),
       sequence(Σ))
```

*For `Cell_D2` **fresh**:*

```js
=let(Σ,counta(B2:B), Λ,"fresh",
       wrapcols(Λ,Σ,Λ))
```

***OR*** this if the import has only data rows (*devoid of any blank rows*)

```js
=let(Λ, your_importrange_function_here, Σ,rows(Λ),
    hstack(sequence(Σ),Λ,wrapcols("fresh",Σ,"fresh")))
```

***UPDATED FORMULA***::

```js
=LET(
    Λ, query(IMPORTRANGE("XXX", "data!A:D"),"where Col1<>''"),
    Σ, ROWS(Λ),
    HSTACK(
        SEQUENCE(Σ),
        Λ,
        arrayformula(if(sequence(Σ),hstack("4","2","0.03","5","≥035","502", "502","9J","3T","7")))
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it generated up to 1000 rows. how can i modify it to only import rows that has value?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: I'm also trying to add a fixed footer for every page of the document, but google sheet do not allow freezing both top and bottom row in a same sheet. I have placed the footer (just some remarks and a signature) in another sheets, can I import the footer once after every 20th row? So that at the bottom of every page there's the same footer.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ukj4Md5GLAqBI6k8fvP_-KrTozmyxcR6SEerFBlWXM/edit?usp=sharing @rockinfreakshow

Comment: Updated the formula in the sheet